# Postman PUT with Bearer Token doesn't work

Tags: ionic-framework, postman, put, bearer-token

I'm try to make an PUT request using Bearer Token but did not work. The only method giving this problem is the PUT method, all other are working fine. Anyone know why ?

[image]

Comment: do you enable the put method on rthe server ? (CORS)

Comment: and also are you sure the correct format is form-url-encoded and not json instead?

Comment: Yeah, to .NET API i'm using form-url-encoded. About authorize PUT on server, I authorize all methods using following command:

 context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

Comment: mm i suggest you to use    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); of using Microsoft.Owin.Cors; and put in your webconfig   <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

Comment: Right, wait a moment.

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: Well, that do not work too, same error as before. :(

Comment: it's really really strange ... can you post your webconfig file and code?

Comment: Wow, wait! Its work! hahaha I dont know whats happened, but did work!

Comment: ahaha ok .. i put as an answer..if iut helps you can you rate it? .. thnx!

Comment: I change to form-data and work. I think it's that x-www-form-urlencoded. Right, Thank you Federico!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks as CORS problem... try to to this .. in your webconfig.xml:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

And then in your StartUp.cs files:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DipendentiStatali.API.Startup))]

namespace DipendentiStatali.API
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {




            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); //<--ALLOW CORS FOR ALL OR FOR WHAT HOST YOU WANT
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Then try to send your request as `JSON` instead of xx-form-urlencoded